# Writing sensor values into a file

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments, android-sensors

I'm trying to let the code writes all the results of **TotalAccelerate** into .txt file. the code writes almost 25 to 26 samples and then stopped by itself.The ToggleButton code isn't working properly, I assume the for loop generates an issue of these samples. It should be more samples than 25 or 26. It should write all the values so I can use them for offline purposes until I toggle off **(!OnStore.isChecked())**. I appreciate your cooperation.

```
  private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

double TotalAccelerate;
ArrayList<Double> list;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = new ArrayList<Double>();

//for Accelermeter
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensor);
    accelermeter = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelermeter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());


    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, "MyMessage.txt");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SDcard not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    OnStore = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onStore);
    OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (OnStore.isChecked()){
                try {
                    for(double TotalAccelerate : list){
                       // System.out.println(TotalAccelerate);
                        String space = "\n";
                        byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                        fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                        String finalData;
                        finalData = String.valueOf(TotalAccelerate);
                        fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());
                    }
                    // fileOutputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }if (!OnStore.isChecked()){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    list.clear();
                    Collections.synchronizedList(list);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

    });
 }//End OnCreate( )


@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    double xx = event.values[0];
    double yy = event.values[1];
    double zz = event.values[2];
    TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(yy, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
    Log.i(DEBUG, "Accelerometer = " + TotalAccelerate);

    list.add(TotalAccelerate);
    findPeaks(list);
   sensorText.setText("Total: " + TotalAccelerate);
    Log.i(DEBUG, "list values " + list);

}
```

Comment: And what is your question really?

Comment: I need all the samples from accelerometer feed into the .txt file until I toggle off the button. How can I do that

Comment: can you help or what?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that Android because of aggressive power management disables the screen and stops the processes and activities that are not visible.

To overcome this you need to run your code in a separate thread and acquire a wakelock, thus, the phone is not getting into the sleep mode. However, better solution is to create a service (which still need to run code in a separate thread) that will be responsible for dealing with sensors.

Comment: Is there anything I can add in my code for the current level?

Comment: It is not that easy to recommend. Basically, I described in the answer what you need to do and what can be an issue in the code. If you want me to write a working solution then, unfortunately, I cannot help you for now. Try look into the Internet - there are plenty examples how to achieve your goal.